# Python import Error "Can not find module src"

Tags: python, flask, factory-pattern

I am facing this error "Can not find module src" while executing command pytest. My create_app function is inside src/ __init__.py

The structure of project is

```
project 

    src
       __init__.py

    tests
       __init__.py
       conftest.py
```

The error is raised from conftest.py when this line is executed

```
from src import create_app
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the src directory is in the python path.
if not try this

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/src')
```